# insert de uma tabela com for

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Tenho o seguinte html:

```
<?php
$j=0;
    while($rows_cursos1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos1)) {
?>

<tr>
<td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="NomeUtente[]" class="NomeUtente" value="<?php echo $rows_cursos1 ["codigo"]; ?>"></td>
<td style="font-size: 12px"><?php echo $rows_cursos1['nome']; ?></td>
<td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="Quarto[]" class="Quarto" value="<?php echo $rows_cursos1 ["quarto"]; ?>"></td>
<td style="font-size: 12px"><?php echo $rows_cursos1['quarto']; ?></td>
<td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="Cama[]" class="Cama" value="<?php echo $rows_cursos1 ["Cama"]; ?>"></td>
<td style="font-size: 12px"><?php echo $rows_cursos1['Cama']; ?></td>
<ul class="flex-outer">
<td style="font-size: 12px"><div class="form-check">
<label class="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="Miccao[<?php $j; ?>]"><span class="label-text"> Realizado</span> <input class="form-control" type="text" name= "Tipo1[]" class= "Tipo1">
</label>
</div></td>
<td style="font-size: 12px"><div class="form-check">
<label class="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="Dejeccao[<?php $j; ?>]"><span class="label-text"> Realizado</span> <input class="form-control" type="text" name= "Tipo[]" class= "Tipo">
</label>
</div></td>
</ul>
</tr>
<?php
$j++;
    }
?>
```

Depois envio os dados para a página com o php com a seguinte função:

```
function inserir_registo26()
{   
   var NomeUtente = [];
    $("input[name^='NomeUtente']").each(function() {NomeUtente.push(this.value)});

    var Quarto = [];
    $("input[name^='Quarto']").each(function() {Quarto.push(this.value)});

    var Cama = [];
    $("input[name^='Cama']").each(function() {Cama.push(this.value)});

    var Miccao = [];
    $("input[name^='Miccao']:checked").each(function() {Miccao.push(this.value)});

    var Tipo1 = [];
    $("input[name^='Tipo1']").each(function() {Tipo1.push(this.value)});

    var Dejeccao = [];
    $("input[name^='Dejeccao']:checked").each(function() {Dejeccao.push(this.value)});

    var Tipo = [];
    $("input[name^='Tipo']").each(function() {Tipo.push(this.value)});

    var dadosajax = {
     'NomeUtente[]' : NomeUtente,
     'Quarto[]' : Quarto,
     'Cama[]' : Cama,
     'Miccao[]' : Miccao,
     'Tipo1[]' : Tipo1,
     'Dejeccao[]' : Dejeccao,
     'Tipo[]' : Tipo
    };
console.log(dadosajax);
    $.ajax({
        url: './registomiccao',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        $('.form11')[0].reset();
        Swal.fire('Boa!', 'Gravado com sucesso!', 'success');
        }
    });
```

o php tenho da seguinte forma:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["NomeUtente"]);$i++) { 

$NomeUtente = $_POST["NomeUtente"][$i];
$Quarto = $_POST["Quarto"][$i];
$Cama = $_POST['Cama'][$i];
$miccao = $_POST["Miccao"][$i];
$Tipo1 = $_POST["Tipo1"][$i];
$dejeccao = $_POST["Dejeccao"][$i];
$Tipo = $_POST["Tipo"][$i];
$Colaborador = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];
$DataRegisto = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if( $miccao != ""){

$miccao1 = $miccao == "on" ? "Realizado" : ""; 

    $query = 'INSERT INTO registoMiccao (`NomeUtente`, `Quarto`, `Cama`, `DataRegisto`, `Miccao`, `Tipo1`, `Colaborador`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
            $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $NomeUtente, $Quarto, $Cama, $DataRegisto, $miccao1, $Tipo1, $Colaborador);
            $stmt->execute();
}
if( $dejeccao != ""){

$dejeccao1 = $dejeccao == "on" ? "Realizado" : "";  

    $query1 = 'INSERT INTO registoDejeccao (`NomeUtente`, `Quarto`, `Cama`, `DataRegisto`, `Dejeccao`, `Tipo`, `Colaborador`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $stmt1 = $conn->prepare( $query1 );
            $stmt1->bind_param("sssssss", $NomeUtente, $Quarto, $Cama, $DataRegisto, $dejeccao1, $Tipo, $Colaborador);
            $stmt1->execute();
}       
}
```

Quando vou inserir, só devia inserir os dados das linhas em que checo as checkbox. Mas o que está acontecer é que se eu checar em duas linhas a checkbox, ele insere apenas duas linhas, mas os dados não pertence às linhas em que chequei as checkboxes.

Por exemplo se eu checar a linha 19 e 20 ele insere os dados da linha 1 e 2 e devia inserir os dados das linhas 19 e 20, porque foram as que chequei.

O problema está nestas linhas:

```
$("input[name^='Miccao']:checked").each(function() {Miccao.push(this.value)});
$("input[name^='Dejeccao']:checked")
```

Porque quando envio os arrays, em todas as variáveis envia 46 linhas e nas checkbox só envia o número de arrays que seleciono, como mostro aqui.

> {NomeUtente[]: Array(46), Quarto[]: Array(46), Cama[]: Array(46),
>   Miccao[]: Array(2), Tipo1[]: Array(46), …}

mas se não colocar o `:checked` nas duas linhas acima ele vai trazer tudo como `on`, como se fossem checados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem um problema no seu código em relação aos seletores quando usa `^=` para pegar `name`'s iniciados pela string `Tipo`.

Veja estas duas linhas:

```
$("input[name^='Tipo1']")
$("input[name^='Tipo']")
```

A segunda linha irá pegar **também** os elementos que iniciam com o `name` `Tipo1`, porque também iniciam com a string `Tipo`.

No seu caso, para pegar os elementos pelo `name` não é preciso usar o seletor `^=`, basta apenas pegar pelo `name` em forma de array acrescentando os colchetes, desta forma:

```
$("input[name='Tipo1[]']")
$("input[name='Tipo[]']")
```

Faça isso também com os demais seletores.

Outra coisa é na função dos `.each` dos elementos checados, ou seja, em relação às arrays `Miccao[]` e `Dejeccao[]`. Retire do seletor o `:checked` para que todos os checkboxes sejam selecionados (não apenas os checados). No `.push()` coloque um `this.checked`. Quando o checkbox estiver checado o `.push()` irá enviar `true`, caso contrário, `false`. Desta forma, essas duas arrays estarão com o mesmo número de itens das outras (pela quantidade de checkboxes).

Por exemplo, se tiver 5 linhas e você marcar a primeira e a terceira linha, a array `Miccao[]` será:

```
[true, false, true, false, false]
```

Os dois `.each` ficarão assim:

```
var Miccao = [];
$("input[name='Miccao[]']").each(function() {
   Miccao.push(this.checked);
});

var Dejeccao = [];
$("input[name='Dejeccao[]']").each(function() {
   Dejeccao.push(this.checked);
});
```

No PHP você pode percorrer as arrays tratando o que estiver `true` de uma forma e o que for `false` de outra:

```
$miccao1 = $miccao ? "Realizado" : "";
```

e

```
$dejeccao1 = $dejeccao ? "Realizado" : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao fazer o filtro dos checkboxes os seus arrays vão ficar com quantidades diferentes. Vejo duas formas de resolver isso: alterar a sua estrutura de dados para um objeto (dará mais trabalho, mas era o melhor) ou simplesmente corrigir o código para pegar todos os checkboxes, mas enviar o valor correto.

Assumindo que é a segunda alternativa que está no escopo da questão, troque as linhas dos checkboxes, como

`$("input[name^='Dejeccao']:checked").each(function() {Dejeccao.push(this.value)});`

Por

`$("input[name^='Dejeccao']").each(function() {Dejeccao.push(this.prop("checked"))});`